# Windows Standalone build module not available in Add Modules List

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, build, module

I am running the Unity 2021.3.22f1 editor. For some reason, the Windows standalone module is not available for download. I am not sure why this is. Do you have to have a licensed version for this module to be available? I see references to this module all over the internet but only in terms of how it is to be used. It almost seems like a given that it should be included. I built my game using the plain Windows build and it works fine but it is not standalone. I had a very clean installation of this version 2021.3.22f1 so it seems strange that this module is not just there unless I am missing something obvious. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What do you mean you built it but its not standalone?

Comment: That is a good question. I figured that the build would result in a single exe file and maybe a data file. But there are several flies and folder in addition to the exe file such as mombleedingEdge, burstdebuginformation. What bothers me the most is that the "standalone" module is just not in my list.

Comment: Well a build is "standalone" but yes you need all the content of that build folder.  Tbh i dont recall seeing the burst one before but i havent hit build on windows for a while.  Build gives you  what you need to give to someone else to play the game. So in effect is standalone. There isnt a one file output or a file and a datafile. There can be many files such as if use 3rd party stuff they hide the. Ode from you in a DLL you got yo use, that DLL will be in there etc